# 'Needs Improvement' button 404ing

Tags: bug, documentation, 404-not-found

I go here:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django

There is one topic that needs improvement, I click 'Improve' it goes here:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/200/4023

Which 404s

Comment: Same thing happens with java tag: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java?tab=needsimprovement the last link (
Minimal inheritance example) leads to a 404